# Why didn't Brigadier General Erinmore try to airdrop his message to Colonel Mackenzie?

Tags: 1917

I'm asking about the 2019 film [*1917*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1917_(2019_film)#Historical_accuracy). An airdrop appears trustworthier, and less risky and bloody than sending two men across [no man's land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_man%27s_land) to reach the abandoned German [trenches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trench_warfare), and not knowing if they delivered the message.

Correct me if I'm wrong about Erinmore's rank, but I see merely [a crossed baton and sword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Army_officer_rank_insignia#History_of_rank_insignia) on his epaulette.

Answer (score 2):

They could not send telegraph because German's had cut their communication lines.

Following are General's dialogues from tent briefings.

> ERINMORE: Colonel Mackenzie is in command of the 2nd. He sent word yesterday
>   morning that he was going after the retreating Germans. He is convinced
>   he has them on the run - that if he can break their lines now, he will
>   turn the tide. He is wrong.
>
> ERINMORE: Colonel Mackenzie has not seen these aerials of the enemy’s new
>   line.
>
> ERINMORE: The 2nd are due to attack the line shortly after dawn tomorrow. They
>   have no idea what they are in for. **And we can’t warn them - as a parting gift, the enemy cut all our telephone lines.**

Since it's not discussed in any length why there was no option of airdrop, my best guess is that they received the new aerials of enemy's lines after the communication was cut off. It was 1917 so definitely someone must have traveled to the General Erinmore to deliver it. Due to loss of communication Erinmore had to resort to postman method to deliver the message to Mackenzie.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question? Why didn't Erinmore send other soldiers to request an airdrop then?

Comment: @Greek - Area 51 Proposal: I agree that Airdrop seems to be a logical step but they were short on time and communication was cutoff.

Comment: While aircraft were pretty much ignored by ground troops and even enemy aircraft (the pilots carried pistols to sometimes shoot at each other) at the beginning of WWI (1914), by 1917 ground troops were shooting them out of the sky and aircraft-to-aircraft warfare had developed high calibre machine guns that shot through the propellers. Flying above 'no mans land' was in no way safe. There's still an active debate as to whether the 'Red Baron' was shot down by an allied plane or ground troops.

Comment: @Jeeped: This would had been logical reason and consequently an answer if General hasn't mentioned of hampered communication.